# Unreal Engine AI not following in new level

Tags: unreal-engine4

I am using Unreal Engine and I created an AI player to follow third person character. This worked fine in the default Third Person Example Map, but when i created a new level, the AI failed to move.

I made 2 pawn sensing components, 1 for Chase and 1 for attack. The attack pawn sensing is working fine in the new level but it is not chasing the player.

The AI was supposed to follow the player but just punched when i came in the punch pawn sensing region.
AI BluePrint :
[image: AI BluePrint]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question might be suited for Game Development Stack Exchange! https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ^^ But while we're here. You're probably best off following a path finding setup tutorial. The problem may just be that you've not setup a nav mesh, but other more subtle things can go wrong.

Comment: Yes you are right. i had not set up navmesh. i did that and it is working fine! thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this :
Go to Edit -> Project Settings -
Navigation Mesh -
Runtime Generation from Static to - Dynamic

You are welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new level make sure that you have a NavMesh inside.
To quickly verify that press P.
If there is a NavMesh in that level it will turn green.

The default Third Person Example Map has already a NavMesh by default.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add “nav mesh bounce volume” to your new level.